# Calculating the proportion of 10,000 samples (of 100 observations) and saving the calculated proportion for each sample

Tags: r, loops

I am doing an task and I am having a small problem with the part of saving the proportion results. The problem is highlighted, I do not know how to save the logs of the proportions. Moreover, how can I put the new 100 samples and the proportion for each other in a loop?

I am going to share the task and the commands I used so far.

**Task**

Open a new script file in R. Use this file to record all operations in R, from opening the file to displaying the last output.
Download AirBnb listings data in Rio de Janeiro (listings.csv) available on the Inside Airbnb website
Load the data into R
Calculate the total number of rows in the database. Hint: command nrow.
Create a binary variable to identify offers for entire houses or apartments (Entire home/apt). Hint: ifelse command.
Calculate the proportion of entire houses or apartments in the complete listing.
**7. Select a random sample of 100 rows from the database. Hint: command sample.
8. Calculate the proportion of entire houses or apartments in the selected sample.**
Repeat steps 7 and 8 10,000 times, saving the calculated proportions for each selected sample in a vector. At the end of the repetitions, the vector with the proportions of each sample should have 10 thousand values. Hint: loop command.

```
library(tidyverse) 
library(data.table) # Adotei o data.table pois ele é uma versão mais eficiente e leve ao trabalhar com dados (e comporta os pacotes que trabalham com data frame)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)

url = "http://data.insideairbnb.com/brazil/rj/rio-de-janeiro/2022-09-21/data/listings.csv.gz"
tmp = tempfile()
download.file(url, tmp)
nrow(data)
dt = data.table(data)
table(dt$room_type)
dt$room_type <- ifelse(dt$room_type == "Entire home/apt", 1, 0)
prop.table(table(dt$room_type)) 
dt100 = dt[sample(nrow(dt), 100), ] 
prop.table(table(dt100$room_type))
```

Comment: Take a look at the manual page for `replicate()` (command: `?replicate`).